# mysql delete statement right syntax

Tags: mysql

ive table olduser  and table user  I need every time to run sql statement to delete users from table user if they are exist in table olduser , i believe to use delete statement but not sure about correct sytnax
any clue !

Comment: The place to get the syntax for something is the manual, not a Q&A site. Type "mysql delete syntax" into a search engine and click the top link. It tells you exactly how to do a delete query involving multiple tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM users 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM olduser)
```

This deletes all rows from the table `users`, if their `id` is in the table `olduser`.

Comment: +1 for making sense of the above...

Answer (score 0):

For the syntax of the delete statement have a look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html

Single-table syntax:

`DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE] FROM tbl_name
     [WHERE where_condition]
     [ORDER BY ...]
     [LIMIT row_count]`